# Method of undefined coefficients for solving linear ODE, singularities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I consider the first order linear ODE of the form
$$ x \frac{dy}{dx}+b\left(x\right)y+c\left(x\right)=0, $$
all the functions $b,c$ are $C^\omega$.

**Question:**
Does this necessarily mean, that solutions of this ODE also belong to $C^\omega$ and so can be found with the help of method of undefined coefficients?
In books I have found a weaker propositions only, when $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are polynomial/sine/etc.